# Excluding column on chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to exclude one column from my chart. In csv I use as my data there is a lot of empty cells and thus there is nameless column in my chart that is at the same highest of them all. In my opinion it looks a bit stupid so I would like to get rid of it.

Here is my chart code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Coverage, fill=(Coverage)))+
  geom_bar(color="black",fill="brown3")+
  theme(text = element_text(size=15),axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))+
  labs(title = "Diagram przedstawiajacy w ktorym miesiacu w kolejnych latach najwieksza liczba dziennikarzy poniosla smierc", x="Panstwo", y="Rok")
```

And here is how the chart looks like. First column is the one counting amount of empty cells.
[image: Image of chart]

thank you very much for all the help!

Comment: Also I would be very thankful if you could tell me why my column descriptions are not right under their columns but instead they are moved to right a bit

Comment: I did as you said but literally nothing changed :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively to @Roman Luštrik's answer, you can use `dplyr` to filter your dataset and do the plot in the same sequence:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>% filter(Coverage != "") %>%
  ggplot(df, aes(Coverage, fill=(Coverage)))+
  geom_bar(color="black",fill="brown3")+
  theme(text = element_text(size=15),axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=0.5))+
  labs(title = "Diagram przedstawiajacy w ktorym miesiacu w kolejnych latach najwieksza liczba dziennikarzy poniosla smierc", x="Panstwo", y="Rok")
```

If this is not working for you, please consider to provide a reproducible example of your dataset (see: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example))

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remove those entries from your `df`. You could so something along the lines of `df[!(df$Coverage %in% c("levels", "to", "exclude", "here")), ]`. If that doesn't work, you may, in addition, need to use `droplevels()`, too.

When you rotate the text, you will also need to offset it a bit, too. You can do it in `theme()` using hjust or vjust (I always forget which one). Something along the lines of `element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0.5)`.

Comment: Is there no simpler way taht would allow me to start chart from second column not first?

Comment: @SauroxGM not with long format. If you have data in wide format, you could perhaps select only `2:ncol(x)`, alas...